# Saving XML as ctypes c_byte in variable gives TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, c, xml, ctypes

In C header file I have :

```
long TEST_API test (    
                        ___OUT_ char DisplayText[41],
                        _IN____ const char XMLparams[2049]
                        );
```

In python code I have imported `ctypes` and I am trying to call "Test".

```
class A(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("DisplayText", c_byte*41), 
                ("XMLparams",c_byte*2049)
            ]

XMLparamsVal = (ctypes.c_byte*2049)(["<xml><MatchboxDataProviderValue>Openvez</MatchboxDataProviderValue><AlwaysPrintTwoTicketsFlag>FALSE</AlwaysPrintTwoTicketsFlag><DisplayWidthInCharacters>20</DisplayWidthInCharacters><!-- exclude Ikea-Card and Maestro from PAN truncation --><DontTruncateList>*119*1*</DontTruncateList></xml>"])

my_A = A("", XMLparamsVal)

lib.test(my_A.DisplayText, my_A.XMLparams)
```

I am gettting this error:

```
XMLparamsVal = (ctypes.c_byte*2049)(["<xml><MatchboxDataProviderValue>Openvez</MatchboxDataProviderValue><AlwaysPrintTwoTicketsFlag>FALSE</AlwaysPrintTwoTicketsFlag><DisplayWidthInCharacters>20</DisplayWidthInCharacters><!-- exclude Ikea-Card and Maestro from PAN truncation --><DontTruncateList>*119*1*</DontTruncateList></xml>"])  
TypeError: an integer is required
```

How can I fix the issue. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, C passes arrays as pointers, so the compiler ignores the 41 and 2049.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `c_byte` array takes a variable number of `int`s as argument, you're trying to give it a list. Try this instead:

```
xml_bytes = bytearray(b'<xml>...')
XMLparamsVal = (ctypes.c_byte*2049)(*xml_bytes)
```

`*xml_bytes` is expanded to a series of positional `int` arguments.

For python3, you wouldn't need the bytearray, you can use a byte literal directly, as in python3 iterating a `byte` object yields `int`s:

```
XMLparamsVal = (ctypes.c_byte*2049)(*b'<xml>...')
```

Note that for the first argument of your `A` class, you'll also have to pass a `c_byte_Array_41`, not a string.

Comment: Or just use a `c_char` array created by `XMLparamsVal = ctypes.c_buffer(b'<xml>...')`. This uses the `c_char` array's `value` descriptor to efficiently initialize the array from a Python string.

Comment: Passing the empty string `""` as the first argument isn't wrong assuming the function expects a pointer to a null-terminated string. However, in this case the parameter isn't `const`, so you should create a buffer. I don't know whether it needs to be at least 41 bytes. Certainly the compiled machine code won't use the 41 and 2049 from the function declaration; the compiler just ignores that. Usually it would be declared as `char DisplayText[]` or `char *DisplayText`. The buffer size has to be passed as a parameter if it isn't null-terminated.